# SharePoint Online - Update list with row totals from another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula

I have a list (ListA) that is populated by an InfoPath form, everytime a user fills in the form another row is added. Now I'm only interested in the 1 value and I want to sum each instance of 1 for each column.

**ListA -**

[image]

I then need this to be populated into a separate single row list (for use in a charting app) in this format:

**ListB -**

[image: ListB]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. ideally with either calculated formula tricks on the UI or a Workflow. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculated formulas work at row level but there is no out of the box approach to doing at column level at storing into a different list.

Using workflow you can achieve. The approach as follows.

Create a SharePoint Designer workflow and run when item inserted.

Here is algorithm to achieve your scenario

```
if currentitem["column1"] == 1
 BEGIIN
   var column1Total = ListB["TotalColumn1"];
   column1Total = column1Total + 1; //use `Do Calculation` action
   ListB["TotalColumn1"] = column1Total;
 END
```

Repeat these conditions for all your 4 columns.

Comment: Thanks  I got it working from your algorithm.. Nice lateral thinking there :)